# Dual boot Ubuntu freezing

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 on a dual booted PC which also has Windows installed.

If I'm on Windows I have no problems whatsoever but when on Ubuntu it keeps freezing from time to time, forcing me to close and open the laptop lid almost constantly.

I believe this problem is not from the lack of memory since i have mroe than enough hard drive space in the Ubuntu partition, and I also have 8GB of RAM.

If anyone has any idea of what the problem might be and how to solve it I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Define freezing? How does closing the laptop help?

Comment: I am unable to move the cursor,  running processes stop like if a webpage is loading it stops , if I'm running a java program on the console it stops...
After closing the lid and opening it again it the processes that stoped complete, like, the java program would start running without any problem, the webpages fail to load since the internet connection got cut off...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this problem now, but did in the past. I only had it briefly, after somebody in here said "get the test kernel".

Other good suggestions are 1) update hardware bios 2) make sure ubuntu firmware is up to date 3) if you are using proprietary video drive, stop for a while to test.

Try to isolate problem.

I would make sure the ssh server is running and log in with another pc when this slowdown happens. It will often be true that an ssh session will be ok, even when computer seems frozen.

One point of this is to see if only your user account is stuck, or the kernel itself is flailing.

In the terminal, run some diagnostics like

```
$ top

$ ps aux | more

$ dmesg
```

You doubt memory trouble, but you also mention Java. I am suspicious, for me Java is a constant source of trouble.

Top will give summary. Ps gives comprehensive output.

Another idea it to try Alt-Ctl-F1 to get to VT. May not work if system is entirely frozen.

I fear that constantly suspending will cause zombie processes to accumulate and you should log out, maybe restart.